# Executing python scripts with "import requests" from a bash script

Tags: python, bash

I have to run a few python scripts and was trying to create a bash script to do it for me. The bash script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash    

FILE=$(ls | grep .\.py)
for f in $FILE
do
    python2.6 $f
done
```

And the following error pops up for each of python calls:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 2, in ?
    import requests
  File "/[some path]/python/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests-2.0.0-py2.6.egg/requests/__init__.py", line 53
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
```

Any ideas would help a lot. Thanks for your time.

EDIT:

Output from

```
import sys
print sys.version
...

2.6.6 (r266:84292, Nov 21 2013, 10:50:32) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)]
```

Comment: The problem seems to be in the Python scripts.  BTW, what's the problem with `for f in *.py`?

Comment: The python scripts work fine if I run them individually from the console. Python scripts that don't have line `import requests` work fine. `$FILE` is just there for when I change the directory.

Comment: Is it probable that your python scripts start with #!/usr/bin/python and pick a different python interpreter ?

Comment: @sateesh No, none of them have a shebang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you go into the interpreter and do `import requests` and it works?

Can you test which version of python you are calling by doing an `import sys`, `print sys.version` before the `import requests`?  Also possibly check your pythonpath variables to make sure you aren't improperly mixing different versions of python.

Also, you seem to be using a rather old version of requests.  It may make sense to upgrade to a newer version (or at least check through the [issues](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues?page=1&state=closed) to see if anyone else has encountered this).

Comment: `import requests` works inside the interpreter. I put the output from `print sys.version` in the main post in an edit. I'm using my school's machines so I'm stuck with this version of requests.

Comment: @MrDiggles - Is the `sys.path` significantly different inside the interpreter (where `import requests` works) than as called from the bash script (where `import requests` doesn't work?)  And again does `import sys` and `print sys.version`, `print sys.path` give the same results in a python script run from a bash file as it does when called  from the interpretter?  If paths are wrong somehow, you can add missing values to `sys.path` manually, or set a bash environmental variable PYTHONPATH or create *.pth files.  As a last resort look into virtualenv and install requests locally.